# I have 1 textbox and checkbox in webform1 and one textbox in seconf webform in vb.net !

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have `textbox1` in Default.aspx vb.net page with `textbox1.text="Sumit"`

On button click event I redirect to Default2.aspx and in Default2.aspx when i click on LinkButton1 then i redirect back to Default.aspx

But then i see the textbox1.text will remove but i want the `textbox1.text="Sumit"` after i redirect to textbox1 again ..

Comment: What???  Is it just me that makes no sense too?

Comment: Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask, specifically the "be specific" point.

Comment: Hey your clicking browser back button....?? then it should be like that only man  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the value of the textbox in Session in the button click event:

```
Session("textbox1_text") = textbox1.text
```

Then in Page_Load event have such code:

```
textbox1.text = Session("textbox1_text")
```

Note, this will set the text to the last text the user wrote always, not just when redircting from page2 so you can add flag on the URL when redirecting and check that flag before assigning the textbox value from session.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `Response.Redirect()` it will load  new page .Use [Cookies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289495%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to store TextBox Values

[check this](http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/35576-How-store-retrieve-cookies-user-s.aspx)